# how to find a text in a gmail body

Tags: google-apps-script

I use this line, to exclude gmail messages:

I have a problem with my last condition, I put "ok!" in my last email answers  and I want that my script excludes all mails that have "ok!" in the body

**if (isMe(lastFrom) &&  lastMessageIsOld && !threadHasLabel(thread, ignoreLabel) && !lastContent.match("ok!") )**

If I use a label instead of  "ok!" everything is perfect, I tried the  -ok!, does not work, -(ok!) not work

please give me another simple solution - thanks renato

Comment: Can you please explain a bit further? Your question is not clear to me.

Answer (score 0):

Per [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match), the argument to `String#match` is a `Regex` object, not a `String`. To match the character sequence "ok!", you would thus want to use

```
lastContent.match(/\bok\b!/)
```

I recommend you review the syntax for regular expressions as well.